# where can I get logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I downloaded the combined Eclipse/ Android SDK a couple of weeks ago.  I really need logging capability and I was disappointed that System.out.println() doesn't write to the console.  After researching the problem, I read that I need to use LogCat to read my logs.  Unfortunately I can't find LogCat in my SDK or anywhere else on my hard drive.  I searched the Internet and didn't find it.

Please help.

Comment: It's just a command in ADB, see here http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: For Android, `System.out.println()` doesn't write to the console, but to the logcat. The console mainly deals with executions of the VM.

Comment: In the lower left of the eclipse window, there is an icon. Click it and choose logcat.

Answer (score 3):

Two way to open logcat window..

**1)first shortcut**

[image: Here is screenshots for shortcut of open Logcat window]

**2)Via Menu**

```
window => Show View => select other... => search logcat
```

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can find Logcat here

`Eclipse->Window->showview->Logcat`

If you don't find logcat option here choose it from `other` option

For command line

goto android-sdk/platform-tools/

`adb logcat`

Answer (score 1):

in eclipse

```
window-->showview-->logcat
```

if logcat is not directly present, then

```
window-->showview-->others(then select logcaqt there)
```

HTH :)

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately I can't find LogCat in my SDK or anywhere else on my
>   hard drive.

=> FYI, Logcat is not a platform tool but a part of ADB.

As you have downloaded ADT Bundle Windows, you can find out ADB inside platform-tools folder:

> \adt-bundle-windows\sdk\platform-tools

Yes if you want to see Logcat output on console, then type **`adb logcat`** at console having above path.

Answer (score 1):

you can find Logcat in Eclipse here :

`Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Logcat`