# My app is crashing when i try to populate a listview

Tags: java, android, methods, call

I am trying to call these methods from another activity and it works almost perfectly, but i get a message telling that my app stopped working whenever it triggers

```
public void retrieveList(){
    DataBaseAdapter adapter = new DataBaseAdapter(this);
    db = adapter.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ficha", null);
}

public void createList(){
    listViewF = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewF);
    CursorAdapterList adapter = new CursorAdapterList(this, cursor);
    listViewF.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

what am i doing wrong?
i don`t know it this is the log but since you asked

```
05-25 16:29:54.343 26925-26925/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10060: Read-only file system
```

also this is the code i`m using to call the methods

```
                        ((FichaActivity)context).retrieveList();
                    ((FichaActivity)context).createList();
                    finish();
```

and yes the methods are inside FichaActivity

Comment: add log stack trace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108360/where-can-i-get-logcat

Comment: You need to post the error logs.

Comment: your list is probably null.... but what does the log say

Comment: edited the post

Comment: did you try to google that error? start there. i found a solution in seconds

Comment: i actually didn't know the error log existed until now so i already have to thank you. i'm going to google now lol

Answer (score 0):

you opened the database as writable, you need to open it as readable

```
db = adapter.getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: yeah it sure was writable but i still get the error

Comment: now it says

    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.rpgm.rpg_m.FichasActivity cannot be cast to com.example.rpgm.rpg_m.FichaActivity

Comment: you have 2 classes one with an "S" in in and one without, and you are trying to cast an object which is of type FichasActivity (with an S) to an object of type FichaActivity (NO S)

Comment: well, yes...
i want to update my listview whenever i add something new, but it is in another activity

Comment: so your app has one activity with a list in it, and another activity where you add an item to it. When you add an item you return to the first activity right? and you want it to refresh

Comment: yes! and in the refresh is where i get the error. it still works though

Comment: You can't call a method in an activity which is currently in the stack from another activity. One thing you could do is: start the second activity for result, insert the new item in your database in the 2nd activity and on success setResult(RESULT_OK) and finish. Then in the first activity in the onActivityResult method simply call retrieveList() and createList().

Comment: also you don't need to create the list every time, you can initialise it and the adapter once, and just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() whenever a change appeared in the item count